# Mirror imaging the Raspbian desktop for GPIO screens

Tags: raspbian, gpio, touchscreen, screen, desktop

How can I make the raspbian desktop look like I am viewing in front of a mirror? (basically backwards) **I've already looked in the documentation for config.txt ([here is a link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md))** and tried to use rotate, but it seems that it rotates the hdmi, not the actual desktop. (but I don't know, because I use RDP) Can somebody please help me figure this out?

Comment: Only time I’ve seen this done (for a back projector) was in the display driver.  A quick check in the x11 manual shows rotation and not flip.

Answer (score 1):

The option you are looking for is

> display_hdmi_rotate

in https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md:

value 0x10000 should perform a horizontal flip, 0x20000 a vertical one.

Comment: By the name, that rotates hdmi. I've tried that and it dint work.

Comment: If you use a gpio screen, you'll need to see if the manufacturer driver allows flipping. For instance, mine don't. Also, I don't think RDP has flipping setting (portrait seems to be ok, but no flip). Do you need all desktop or only your app to be flipped ? If only your app, it could be easier to flip what you show.

Comment: Desktop, and I dont need RDP to be flipped.